# Can someone solve this mathematical expression in special relativity for me?

Tags: special-relativity, geometry

How do we get to the end expression from the start one by substituting $\phi=\tanh^{-1}(v)$?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to the Physics.SE. A starting point could be https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivations_of_the_Lorentz_transformations or in this file http://sites.science.oregonstate.edu/~tevian/physics/paradigm9/sample/excerpt2.pdf

Comment: This is not math.stackexachange